# python: Django import fails asking me to define DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am newbee in Django.I finished the Django Tutorial once from the official **djangoproject** site.Not saying I know everything now, but everything worked perfectly for me till I was referring that website.
I started referring to the **Practical Django projects** book and somewhere in my models I tried to import :

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

gives me an import error :

`ImportError Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined`
`

What is really going on here ? I have been successfully importing all the packages till now then why this sudden error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running the code that gives you the error? If you are importing the `models.py` in the shell, use the [Django shell command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell])

```
./manage.py shell
```

If you are trying the import in another script, you have to set the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` manually.

```
import os

if 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
```

This requires `myproject` to be in your python path.

See this similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641444/why-am-i-getting-this-error-in-django) for futher discussion.

Comment: I was testing the import from another directory different from my site's directory. Is that why that happened ?

Comment: The directory you are in doesn't matter. You just need to ensure that the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable is set correctly and the project directory is in your python path.